# If I send a WM_KEYDOWN message (using wndproc) will the computer hold the key down until I send WM_KEYUP?

Tags: windows, keyboard, simulation, wndproc

I am looking for a solution to programmatically hold a keyboard key down during some time (I don't know how many time).

I think that if I send a WM_KEYDOWN message the key will be held down until WM_KEYUP is send, but I am not sure.

I would test it. But I need to go and I don't have much time. I want to see if someone already tested this.

Here is an other question I posted, related to this one.
[I want to make a virtual keyboard. Do I need to send WM_KEYDOWN to the current active window or HWND_BROADCAST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090058/i-want-to-make-a-virtual-keyboard-do-i-need-to-send-wmkeydown-to-the-current-ac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because If you examine the messages sent when using the keyboard, you'll see that the message are as follow:

```
WM_KEYDOWN
WM_KEYPRESS
WM_KEYUP
```

The `WM_KEYPRESS` message is sent every couple of ticks (depending on the keyboard configuration).

Comment: So I need to send WM_KEYDOWN
then send WM_KEYPRESS repetevely and then stop and send an WM_KEYUP message.

will this work?

Answer (score 0):

WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP are messages generated by the system - it's dependent on how the application interprets those messages.  Synthesizing these messages will have no effect on the actual keyboard state.

If you want to simulate keyboard input, use the [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(VS.85).aspx) API.