# I want to make a virtual keyboard. Do I need to send WM_KEYDOWN to the current active window or HWND_BROADCAST?

Tags: windows, keyboard, simulation, wndproc

I am making an app that simulates a keyboard.
I will do it by sending WM_KEYDOWN to a window, but I am not sure where to send the message.
to the currently active window or to HWND_BROADCAST?

Here is an other question I posted, related to this one.
[If I send a WM_KEYDOWN message (using wndproc) will the computer hold the key down until I send WM_KEYUP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089968/if-i-send-a-wmkeydown-message-using-wndproc-will-the-computer-hold-the-key-dow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If make a generic virtual keyboard and not worry about which window is active (which is the window manager's business), you can use SendInput: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(VS.85).aspx